# HTTP Error 401: Authorization Required while downloading a file from HTTPS

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, urllib, monday.com

I'm encountering some "error 401: Unauthorized" problems while trying to download a file from a secure server.  Here's what I ran -

```
>>> import urllib.request
>>> username = [My_Username]
>>> password = [My_Password]
>>> baseurl = "https://[Server]"
>>> manager = urllib.request.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
>>> manager.add_password(None, baseurl, username, password)
>>> auth = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(manager)
>>> opener = urllib.request.build_opener(auth)
>>> urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
>>> reponse = urllib.request.urlopen(baseurl + [rest of File_URL])
```

Error -

```
**raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)**
**urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized**
```

I also tried another method I found on Stack Overflow but didn't work -

```
>>> response = requests.get(url, verify = False, auth=(username, password))
>>> response
<Response [401]>
```

url being the full address of the file (baseurl + [rest of File_URL]).

Should be noted that when I enter the File URL to the address field of my browser, it downloads.

Thanks!

Comment: Base 64 auths are usually base64 encoded in the format base64encode(username:password). 
you can try the following:
```>> import base64
>> api_auth = base64.b64encode(f"{username}:{passoword}")
>> response = requests.get(url, verify = False, {"Authorization": "basic {}".format( api_auth)```

Comment: @RishabhBatra I'm getting an error when running the second line -
    encoded = binascii.b2a_base64(s, newline=False)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: that's probably because you are using binascii library, which has a completely different function. You have to base64 encode while you trying to convert from binary to ascii. Try, base64.b64encode function.